# not able to create configurable products in magento from backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have created Color and size attribute with type drop-down in configurable Attribute Set. Also I have added many color and Size to that attribute.
I have created configurable Set with the Configurable Product type. then Select both drop-down. Then I put name, SKU, Images, price, inventory keep as In stock. And assign the product to category. Also set Website. After that I create associate products.

I am not able to see the configurable products on frontend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Have you checked that they are actually associated to the configurable product? Are the associated simple products in stock, active etc? Be sure to have everything valid (it sounds banal but easily missed).

Answer (score 0):

//Please reconfirm following points for configurable and associate simple products. .

```
1.Enable,Visibility,Stock,Qty 
2.Reindexing and Clear cache.
```

[More details refer this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/)

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have tried above link. but product detail page not displaying. Shows, Not Found.